# Evaluating an integral using Riemann sum.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, riemann-sum

I was trying to evaluate the following integral $\int_0^{10} 2^x$ using Riemann sum.

What I tried:

$\triangle x_i= \frac{10-0}{n}=\frac{10}{n}$

$x_i=x_0 + i\triangle x_i = 0 + i\frac{10}{n}=i\frac{10}{n}$

Let $f(x)=2^x$.

Hence $f(x_i)=2^{x_i}=2^{i\frac{10}{n}}$

$S_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f(x_i).\triangle x_i$

$S_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{10}{n}.2^{i\frac{10}{n}}$

$S_n=\frac{10}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 2^{i\frac{10}{n}}$

$S_n=\frac{10}{n}({2^{\frac{10}{n}}}^0+{2^{\frac{10}{n}}}^1+...+{2^{\frac{10}{n}}}^{n-1})$

$S_n=\frac{10}{n}.\frac{1-{2^{\frac{10}{n}}}^n}{1-2^{\frac{10}{n}}}$

$S_n=\frac{10}{n}.\frac{1-2}{1-2^{\frac{10}{n}}}$

$S_n=\frac{10}{(2^\frac{10}{n}-1)(n)}$

$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} S_n =\frac{1}{log2}$ Which doesn't evaluate to $\int_0^{10} 2^x$

Can someone tell me where I've gone wrong ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{10}n\cdot\dfrac{1-(2^{10/n})^n}{1-2^{10/n}}=\dfrac{2^{10}-1}{\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{2^{10/n}-1}{\dfrac{10}n}}$$

Now setting $10/n=h,$ $${\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{2^{10/n}-1}{\dfrac{10}n}}=\ln2\cdot\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{e^{h\ln2}-1}{h\ln2}=?$$

Comment: Oh damn such a dumb mistake I've made.

Comment: I'm sure you need a limit in the first expression to pass to taking a limit in the second and onwards.

Comment: @Chris, Thanks for your observation